# « Allez cuisine ! » : l'impératif suivi de l'inanimé comme signal de départ d'une compétition ?

Tags: alimentation, syntaxe, interjections, impératif, noms-collectifs

Dans une [émission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Chef) japonaise fort prisée des années 1990 où deux chefs s'affrontent dans un « stade culinaire » (*Kitchen Stadium* : une cuisine aménagée pour deux équipes, devant public en studio), le [présentateur](https://youtu.be/i6r9Cg2o4wY?t=10m50s) (M. Takeshi Kaga), après avoir dévoilé l'ingrédient thème, donne le signal de départ de la compétition en déclarant énergiquement « **Allez cuisine !** ». C'est l'impératif suivi du nom inanimé... Dans une foire aux questions quelqu'un en [discutait](http://web.archive.org/web/20041021204843/http://www.ironfans.net:80/faq/#allez) et en était venu à la conclusion que la phrase était incorrecte puis suggérait diverses réinterprétations : « *Allez ! Cuisine !* », « *Allez cuisiner !* », « *Allez ! Cuisinez !* » et « *Allez à la cuisine !* ».

---

- Connaît-on d'autres emplois de l'impératif suivi du nom inanimé dans un contexte de compétition (ou qui serait relié par analogie) ?
- Le nom [*cuisine*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cuisine) fait-il l'objet d'un emploi pour désigner un ensemble de personnes dans certains contextes ; y a-t-il métonymie ou
  un tour s'appuyant sur un registre particulier dans l'exemple de l'émission ?
- Pourquoi la phrase serait-elle cohérente ou non ? Pourquoi telle ou telle autre phrase ou tour conviendrait davantage ?

Comment: Par curiosité,  j'ai été voir sur YouTube un extrait de l'émission. Personnellement, le présentateur me semble dire une accroche qui "sonne bien"... mais ne parle sans doute pas un mot de français et répète deux mots sans se soucier de savoir s'ils sont corrects...."Cuisine" est un mot passé en anglais, et un ordre en français évoque sans doute la gastronomie pour le public japonais.

Comment: @Greg Merci ! Je connais fort bien l'émission, j'en ai visionné des centaines, et plusieurs fois ! Il y a une sorte de romantisme avec certaines références françaises dont celle de Rimbaud (voir art. wiki premier lien). Je crois que vous sous-estimez p.-ê. un peu la production, mais en effet c'est une émission japonaise et M. Kaga parle japonais et on ne peut pas nécessairement s'attendre à ce qu'il y a de plus idiomatique et on connaît l'attrait de la gastronomie française en effet. Perso. je crois que c'est un truc recherché, qui évoque le grandiose...

Answer (score 2):

Sur le 2ème point: *cuisine* peut effectivement désigner,  par métonymie, l'ensemble du personnel qui travaille en cuisine.

> La cuisine se plaint des nouveaux horaires.
>
> Vous pouvez féliciter la cuisine.

À la premiere lecture et sans connaître le contexte, c'est dans ce sens que je comprends "allez, cuisine!" mais on peut plutôt attendre alors un article défini:

> Allez, la cuisine!

Sur le même modèle que "allez, les verts" ou "allez l'Olympique" !

Comment: Merci ! Concernant la dernière ligne, c'est bien le [foot](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allez_les_Verts_!) et le [rugby](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympique_(rugby_%C3%A0_XV)) si je comprends bien ou était-ce l'ancien [_Olympique_](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympique_(football)) (foot) dont vous parliez ; je pensais que le premier c'était les écolos réf: politique.

Comment: Je ne pensais pas à un sport en particulier, cela peut s'appliquer au foot ou au rugby mais aussi à d'autres sports, et on peut se référer aux couleurs, au nom du club, mais aussi à la ville (*allez Paris !*) ou à un surnom (*allez les hurlus !*). Et je n'avais pas du tout pensé à un même usage en politique... ce serait inattendu, mais pas impossible.

Answer (score 2):

L'expression fait penser aux ordres ***moteur !*** et ***action !*** que l'on peut entendre durant le tournage de films, ou ***musique !*** pour demander à un orchestre de commencer à jouer.

Vu qu'elle donne aussi un signal de départ, elle signifie très probablement ici :

> **Allez, cuisine !** → Allez, que la cuisine commence ! (= commencez à cuisiner)

à l'instar de :

> [Allez,] **musique** (maestro) **!** → que la musique commence ! (= commencez à jouer)
>
> [[Allez,] **moteur !**](https://youtu.be/8RWLPxw3Aoo) → démarrez les caméras (= commencez à filmer)
>
> [Allez,] **action !** → commencez à jouer la comédie

Answer (score 1):

Pour ma part, je l'interprète comme "Allez ! Cuisine !", c'est-à-dire deux impératifs successifs.
A vrai dire, "Allez" n'est pas réellement un verbe conjugué
puisque l'on peut dire "Allez, dépêche-toi !" (c'est-à-dire utiliser deux verbes dans la même phrase en passant du vouvoiement au tutoiement).

Il me semble que "Allez !" est le plus souvent utilisé avec un verbe conjugué
quand il n'est pas tout seul. J'ai déjà cité "Allez, dépêche-toi",
mais il y a aussi "Allez, on y va", "Allez, je ramasse les copies".
On l'emploie parfois avec un adverbe ("Allez, plus vite !"),
mais je n'ai jamais entendu "Allez, musique !" ou "Allez, moteur".
En plus, dire "Allez, cuisine !" où cuisine est un nom
m'évoque "Aller cuisine".

Comment: Voilà une suite mémorable d'**[allez moteur !](https://youtu.be/8RWLPxw3Aoo)**